# Fantasy novel. A group of adventures fight a mage using a red and blue gem that can only be used by specific genders

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was younger I read a series that had to do with a group of people trying to defeat a powerful evil mage. The group included the male main character, a female main character, a harpy, and a young werewolf.

They had had in their possession at some point a magical red gem that only men could use, and a magical blue gem that only women could use, or vice versa.

I remember one book having a big battle at the end between the group and the villain in the confines of a Dwarven mountain cave, wherein the blue gem was stuck to the ceiling of their base in the mountain, and the characters had to figure out how to get it before the baddy showed up

The next book in the series started with the male main character traveling alone in possession of the men only magical gem, and using it to force a fire spell to work on some trolls while traveling through a snowy mountain pass. I'm not sure if it helps but one mechanic of the magic they used in this series was that once a spell had been used, nobody could ever use that exact spell again the same way, and I believe the gems could bypass this rule but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was this aimed at young adults or adults (with sex/violence/gore)? What were the names of the party members? What were the names of the places they visited? What was the setting for their adventures? Why did they meet? How did they know about the evil mage? Was the gem called a "gem" or was there another word used (like "gemstone" or "firestone" or whatever)? How 'young' was the werewolf? How did people cast spells (did they say words or just think them)? What language did you read this book in? What was on the cover?

Comment: In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?